# Ошибка This does not look like a tar archive при попытке извлечь файлы tar

Tags: linux, bash, tar, сжатие, compression

Не могу понять, почему возникает эта ошибка.

```bash
mkdir test && cd test
mkdir files
touch files/{1,2,3}
tar --create --file "test.lzma" files/{1,2,3} --auto-compress
mkdir extracted_files
tar --extract --file "test.lzma" --directory extracted_files --auto-compress
```

> tar: This does not look like a tar archive

```
xz --version                                                                                                                                                       
 xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.7
 liblzma 5.2.7
tar --version                                                                                                                                                      
 tar (GNU tar) 1.34
file test/test.lzma                                                                                                                                                
 test/test.lzma: LZMA compressed data, streamed
ls test/extracted_files/                                                                                                                                           
 files
```

То есть вроде бы всё работает, но сообщение об ошибке есть...

Интересно, что на https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell не воспроизводится, а на https://replit.com/languages/bash — воспроизводится. Мб это какой-то баг.

Comment: btw чем отличаются метки [tag:сжатие] и [tag:compression]?

Comment: с программами gnu/tar версии 1.34 и lzma версии 5.2.5 ошибка не воспроизводится. рекомендую для начала разобраться, что же у вас получилось внутри файла `test.lzma`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin `xz --version` 5.2.7, `tar` такой же, как у вас. Вывод `file test.lzma` - `test.lzma: LZMA compressed data, streamed`. Кстати, файлы присутствуют то в итоге, но ошибка почему-то есть.

Comment: 1. ну, распакуйте программой lzma, и посмотрите что там. 2. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/178576

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin распаковал через `unlmz`, там файл `test`, который является `tar` архивом и нормально распаковавается без ошибок...

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin о, на https://replit.com/languages/bash получилось воспроизвести, там `tar (GNU tar) 1.34` и `xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.2`

Comment: воспроизводится и со свежими версиями из guix: `$ guix shell --container xz tar coreutils bash -- bash test.sh`

Comment: да, что-то не в порядке с автодетектом у tar. если суффикс заменить на `.xz`, ошибки не возникает.